# Hide part or script's output

Tags: bash, svn, scripting

I wrote a script which does some operations with SVN, everything is working fine, but I want to suppress the output of certain commands executed by the script. The following code is a minor part of this script and i want to hide all output when it executes a section containing `"sudo svn add *"`

```
ng1=$(svn stat 2>&1 | grep "?")
    if [[ "$ng1" != "" ]];
    then
        echo ' '
        echo '[NGINX]New files in work folder, add???[y/n]?'
        echo ' '
        read qyn    
        case $qyn in
            [yY]* ) sudo svn add *;; #Add all to repo
            [nN]* ) echo ' ';; #Proceed further
        esac
    else
        echo ' '
        echo '[NGINX]No new files'
        echo ' '        
    fi
```

I tried to redirect ouput this way - `{sudo svn add *} &>/dev/null` but it's not working.
Is there any way to hide this output, but still execute `sudo svn add *`

Comment: It's not working because you have syntax errors: you need spaces and a semi-colon like this: `{ sudo svn add *; } &>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress both stdout and stderr use this:

```
sudo svn add * >& /dev/null
```

OR:

```
sudo svn add * &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one earlier, but i used { } to define whole block and then redirect it. This was my mistake

Comment: In `{` and `}` you need `;` before `}` like `{ sudo svn add * >& /dev/null; }`

Comment: Sure! Thanks again, helped to hide all the debug output to make it more user friendly)